# Will making time-lapse videos for several hours with my DSLR wear out the sensor?

Tags: timelapse

The title says it all. I'm using a DSLR. Will making a time-lapse video, which requires several hours to shoot, wear out the sensor?

Comment: I would be worried about the shutter and the mirror, not the sensor. I would use electronic shutter and mirror lockup, if available.

Comment: Related: [Did shooting in burst mode wear out my shutter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/79078/15871) and [Life expectancy of an electronic shutter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/80042/15871)

Answer (score 1):

Sensor wear usually means burned pixels. This only happens when shooting **continuous** video without letting the camera cool down. Since timelapse doesn't mean continuos recording, *sensor wear* that would be of concern.

Shutter wear, on the other hand, is a valid concern. Every camera has an *average* shuttercount limit (check [this website](http://www.olegkikin.com/shutterlife/) for actual numbers). To conserve as much of your shutter's lifetime as possible, I suggest what @juhsit also mentioned: If your camera has a way to set the timelapse to use mirror-lockup and electronic shutter, use that, as it should mean only one shutter actuation per timelapse.

Answer (score 0):

No more than taking the equivalent number of exposures while doing street photography or sports photography or studio photography.

Possibly less wear if you use the mirror lock-up and electronic shutter as others have mentioned.